# Incorrect Permission Assignment For Critical Resources - certificación chekmarx

Tags: java, primefaces, java-stream

Estoy certificando un proyecto en chekmarx, y para el error "Incorrect Permission Assignment For Critical Resources" me pide asignar permisos de escritura a un archivo que estoy creando de la siguiente manera:

```
public void exportCSV(){
        ByteArrayOutputStream archivoTmp = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter streamWriter = null;
        streamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(archivoTmp);
        PrintWriter printWriter = null;
        printWriter = new PrintWriter(streamWriter);
        try {
            printWriter.write(title + "\n");
            printWriter.flush();
            printWriter.close();
            dao.makeCSV(usuarioVo.getPaisSeleccionado().getIdPais(),opcSeleccionado,1,util.formatoFechaABase(fechaInicial), util.formatoFechaABase(fechaFinal),printWriter);
            ByteArrayInputStream streamed = new ByteArrayInputStream(archivoTmp.toByteArray());
            archivoTmp.
            archivo = new DefaultStreamedContent(streamed, "text/csv", "Detalle.csv");
            streamWriter.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            archivo = null;
            log.error("Ocurrió un error al escribir el archivo de exportación: ", ex);
        }
    }
```

Como le asigno permisos de escritura (-rw-r--r--) a un PrintWriter o al OutputStreamWriter o al ByteArrayOutputStream o al DefaultStreamedContent?.

Comment: `DefaultStreamedContent` es una clase se PrimeFaces cierto?

Comment: Es correcto, si tienes alguna idea, por mas mínima que parezca es bienvenida.

Comment: Que tal, da una  leída a sobre PosixFilePermission del paquete nio de java. Te dejo un enlace que puede ser de utilidad : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860448/java-set-file-permissions-to-several-users